# Factor symbolic expression involving exp()

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, exp

I have a symbolic function exp(a+b), and would like to factor out A=exp(a) to produce exp(a+b) = A*exp(b), but I cannot figure out how to do this in MATLAB. Below is my attempt:

```
syms a b A
X = exp(a+b);
Y = subs(X,exp(a),A) % = A*exp(b)
```

however, Y = exp(a+b). For some reason, MATLAB cannot determine:
exp(a+b) = exp(a) * exp(b) = A*exp(b).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`expand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/expand.html) the expression so that the exponents are separated **then do the substitution**.  By default, when writing out an expression for the first time (before running it through any functions), MATLAB will try and simplify your expression and so `exp(a)*exp(b)` can be much better expressed using `exp(a+b)`.  This is why your substitution had no effect.  However, if you explicitly want to replace a part of the expression that is encompassed by an exponent with a base, expand the function first, then do your substitution:

```
>> syms a b A;
>> X = exp(a+b);
>> Xexpand = expand(X)

Xexpand =

exp(a)*exp(b)

>> Y = subs(Xexpand, exp(a), A)

Y =

A*exp(b)
```